# Create an app in azure AD for sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint, office365, office365-apps, office365api

Hie everyone,

Can anyone tell me how i can create an application for **SharePoint online** please?

I'm using **Azure AD** and there is no option(1) for sharepoint online, i only see the graph application for the unified API.

[image]
Thanks a lot

(1) 2 weeks ago there were an app called **Offfice365 Sharepoint**, but it disappeared

Answer (score 1):

Based on the image it looks like you don't have SharePoint enabled for the account that was used to login to the Azure Portal. You need to have an active license for SharePoint to be able to register an application in the Azure Portal that accesses SharePoint data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i just subscribed a regular 30 days trial. I used to have a previous account, also in 30 days trial, and i did had the Office365 Sharepoint App by default. What has in changed in Azure AD since then and how to activate this licence? Thanks

Comment: I tried adding the only licence i see, Azure Active Directory Premium, i also assigned it to myself, but that doesnt give me this office365 online app. I don't understand, it was my default before.

Comment: I also tried Enterprise mobility Client licence, and still, no office365 sharepoint app

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I am going to try answer it. With Visual Studio 2015 you can create to types of SharePoint Add-ins, SharePoint Hosted and Provider Hosted. In order to create a Provider Hosted Add-in that you want to host on Azure you can use the Publish feature in Visual Studio. Right click the Web Project and Select Publish. When creating the Publishing Profile select the target for [Microsoft Azure App Service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhIbM.jpg). From there you will be ask to provide the information for your Azure account and can create Resource Groups and App services that will host your Provided Hosted Add-in in Azure.